# Por que é que o pronome 'eu' deve vir no final?

Tags: pronomes, regência, ordem-de-expressões

Em frases como:

> (i) Eu, fulano, sicrano e beltrano faremos a execução da primeira etapa do projeto.

Ou

> (ii) Fulano, sicrano, beltrano e eu faremos a execução da primeira etapa do projeto.

O exemplo (ii) seria, supostamente, o mais correto...

Por que é que o pronome *eu* deve aparecer no fim?

Comment: À 1a vista não me parece _mais correta_ nenhuma das versões, ambas parecem certas. Qual a fonte desta sua percepção?

Comment: Denis, não sei se reparaste, mas eu mudei o teu *siclano* para *sicrano*, que é o que vem no dicionário. Mas claro está, o dicionário não é lei. Se preferires *siclano*...

Comment: Ok, Jacinto. Ficou melhor assim. Eu fui pego pela pronuncia que geralmente é incorreta, ou seja, siclano.

Comment: @gmauch, não é uma percepção cientifica. Vi isso no programa do Chaves <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeM_eR5i5VY>. Depois fiz uma pesquisa na internet e encontrei alguns textos assim.

Comment: Denis, encontrei uma coisa curiosa numa gramática. Vê edição da resposta.

Comment: @someonewithpc mudaste no título o *por que* da norma brasileira para o *porque* da norma europeia.

Comment: @Jacinto, muito bom. A citação da obra de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra melhorou ainda mais a resposta.

Comment: @someonewithpc, prefiro manter a norma brasileira dos porquês, neste caso, *por que*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra na sua *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* (Lisboa, 1984, p. 365-6) dão-te alguma razão:

> Quando no sujeito composto há um da 1.ª pessoa do singular (*eu*), é boa norma de civilidade colocá-lo em último lugar:
>
> **Carlos, Augusto e eu** fomos promovidos.
>
> Se, porém, o que se declara contém algo de desagradável ou importa responsabilidade, por ele devemos iniciar a série:
>
> **Eu, Carlos e Augusto** fomos os culpados do acidente.

Digo apenas *alguma razão*, porque a posição do *eu* deve depender segundo eles de o que se tem a dizer ser agradável ou não. Mas mais importante, os autores recomendam isto como uma «norma de civilidade»; do ponto de vista gramatical, ambas as ordenações são igualmente corretas, e na minha experiência é até mais comum começar com o *eu*.

Uma busca no Google Books parece confirmar que não é só na minha experiência. Isto parece ser independente de o nome ser ou não precedido de artigo. Excluí nomes compostos (João Luís, Pedro Miguel, etc. do *eu e [nome]*).

**Resultados da Busca no Google Books**

```
             eu e [nome]    [nome] e eu
a Beatriz        17              3
a Raquel         17              3
a Sofia          24              6
Sofia            26              9
o João           36             11
João             12              7
o Matheus         7              4
o Pedro          36             10
```

É possível no entanto que tivesse havido entre alguns autores clássicos uma preferência pelo *eu* no fim. Numa vista de olhos por este [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) encontrei vários *[nome] e eu* na obras de [Machado de Assis (1839-1908](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machado_de_Assis) e [Eça de Queiroz (1845-1900)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Maria_de_E%C3%A7a_de_Queir%C3%B3s), mas nenhuns *eu e [nome]*. Já [Júlio Dinis (1839-71)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%BAlio_Dinis) põe o *eu* no princípio em várias ocasiões.

E até se encontram as duas construções na mesma obra, como nesta [canção de Pedro Abrunhosa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4WVNL9QrT4), com [a letra completa aqui](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Pedro-Abrunhosa/Talvez-Foder-Vers%C3%A3o-Longa) (ênfase minha):

> Há bombas em Belfast e em Beirute
> É preciso afinar o azimute
> E **eu e tu** o que é que temos que fazer? Talvez […]
> E **tu e eu** o que é que temos que fazer? Talvez […]

Answer (score 7):

Essa é uma regra, talvez não de gramática, mas de etiqueta, em inglês. Primeiro você, depois eu. Em português não me parece que seja dada importância à posição relativa dos pronomes.

Comment: Também foi o meu primeiro palpite, na língua inglesa por questões de etiqueta é considerado mais correcto enunciar outras pessoas antes de nos referirmos a nós mesmos, no entanto penso que não exista tal regra em Português.

Comment: Escrito não parece haver diferença, mas falado o 'eu' no começo fica perdido na frase. O 'eu' no final reforça sua participação na ação na linguagem oral. E ainda é mais fácil de pronunciar.